# How to Read error body in Retrofit when response is not successful?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit in Android for api execution.

**Sample Snippet**

```
 Call<UniversalPojo> call = apiInterface.storeData(AppClass.getInstance().getLoggedInUser().getRemember_token(), requestBody);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<UniversalPojo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UniversalPojo> call, Response<UniversalPojo> response) {
                
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        
                    } else {
                       
                       //I want to read code at this stage in string.
                       
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UniversalPojo> call, Throwable t) {
 
                    t.printStackTrace();
                  

                }
            });
```

My question here is how to obtain the error in String at else block of if (response.isSuccessful()).

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: you can have `response.code()` to check for response codes

Answer (score 0):

use `OkHttpClient` class's `addInterceptor(interceptor: Interceptor)` function

override the `intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain)` function and throw exceptions as you expected:

```
class NetInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        val code = response.code
        val body = response.body
        // if body is null or something unexpected
        throw IOException("receive empty body")
        // else do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using java i will convert this code, though i have added interceptor to retrofit client, but how shall i get the response in the else block i have written in question, I am doing this for error tracking purpose.

Comment: you can get the response body  using `response.body.string` and deserialize to an object with Gson.  after the tracking things, just `return response.newBuilder().body(bodyString.toResponseBody(body.contentType())).build()`.